# How to call php function inside echo?

Tags: php

My data are usually taken from mysql however that's not the issue. My problem is i want to be able to call few functions inside an echo. I dont even know if it is possible. Im almost new to php Please any help is appreciated.

```
<?php
     echo"
        <div class='container'>
          <select name='science'>
         <?php science_facts(); ?>
          </select>
        </div>
    ";      
?>
```

or

```
<?php
    echo"
          <div class='container'>
            <select name='science'>
           science_facts();
           </select>
        </div>  
   ";   
?>
```

Both not working.

Comment: The second one, but break out of the string. Concatenate `'science'>" . science_facts() . "`

Comment: have you tried with print_r ??

Comment: `Im almost new to php` so what your saying is your not completely new?

Comment: never used print_r  sorry!

Comment: Theoretically, `<? php` there shouldn't be a space in that, should it be your real code. However, that shouldn't even be in there, you're already in PHP and should have gotten back a parse error for it.

Comment: `science_facts()` what does that function do and does it return anything? You're not doing anything with that function. People in answers may not have caught that. Edit: Actually, one did, being Alex.

Comment: that function returns option value of form

Comment: *Again...* just having `science_facts()` like that does *do* anything.

Comment: i think i will try something now thanks though.

Comment: You do know how to mark a question as solved, right? If not, there's a checkmark next to an answer, you give it a tick till it turns green ;-) Alex's answer to me, would be the best one, IMHO.

Comment: oh i will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to break up the string into its static and dynamic parts. There are numerous ways to do this but the two most common are to use multiple echo statements:

```
echo "<div class='container'>";
echo "<select name='science'>";
echo science_facts(); // Note no quotes!
echo "</select>";
echo "</div>";
```

Or use the `.` string concatenation operator to join strings on the fly:

```
echo "<div class='container'>" .
    "<select name='science'>" .
    science_facts() .
    "</select>" .
    "</div>";
```

Or, the same in one line:

```
echo "<div class='container'><select name='science'>" . science_facts() . "</select></div>";
```

Or start/stop PHP execution explicitly:

```
...
?>
<div class='container'>
<select name='science'>
<?php echo science_facts(); ?>
</select>
</div>
<?php
...
```

(Note: This assumes that your `science_facts()` function returns its output rather than echoing it.)

Comment: Why not `?><div ...><?php`  to flip modes?

Comment: Could also assign it to a variable and then put the variable in and let interpolation do it's thing...  Could end and start PHP ... etc.  Many ways.

Comment: Right like I said... numerous ways... :)

Comment: I think i should try this,

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Soooo... beer time?

Comment: @AlexHowansky Kind'ish LOL!! But *cheers!* I'll stick to coffee :-))

Comment: @AlexHowansky Are there some official docs on how you did this? It does not work for me - ty.

Answer (score 0):

In my case puting function inside echo resulted in displaying result of a function before input tag (weird). My solution was end echo function than trigger function and continue echo.

Not working (displaying result of function before 'input' tag):

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="zabezpieczenie' . $idZabezpieczenia . '" name="zabezpieczenie' . $idZabezpieczenia . '" value="zabezpieczenie' . $idZabezpieczenia . '" onclick="dodaj_czynnosc(this.value, this.id)"'.checkChecked('zabezpieczenie' . $idZabezpieczenia).'>';
```

Working (displaying result of function inside 'input' tag):

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="zabezpieczenie' . $idZabezpieczenia . '" name="zabezpieczenie' . $idZabezpieczenia . '" value="zabezpieczenie' . $idZabezpieczenia . '" onclick="dodaj_czynnosc(this.value, this.id)"';
checkChecked('zabezpieczenie' . $idZabezpieczenia); //displays checked
echo '>';
```